# Questions on algorithm complexity, not related to any particular code

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, site-recommendation

What should we do with theoretical questions on algorithm complexity not associated with any programming code?

Can they be moved to [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) or any other better suited site?

Here's just one example: [Time-compexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523484/time-compexity-of-an-algorithm)

I noticed that the Computer Science site actually has a [`complexity-theory`](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/complexity-theory/info) tag.

Answer (score 8):

Based on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> #### Computer Science
>
> For questions about computer science, as in the academic discipline. As a rule of thumb, if your question depends on real-life languages/code/hardware/..., ask on Stack Overflow; if your question calls for abstract/mathematical models and reasoning, ask on Computer Science. Algorithms expressed in pseudocode straddle the border.

Computer Science will be a better fit than Stack Overflow. The users on Computer Science have (on average) a more mathematical background than they do here, which is necessary to provide good answers to these kind of questions.

Comment: That sounds to me like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453793/which-is-the-fastest-algorithm-to-find-prime-numbers) should be migrated